# jquery scrollTo not working in IE with negative vlaues

Tags: jquery, scrollto

i'm building a small presentation website for a company intranet.
it will be basically a number of screens or panels laid out horizontally, with navigation buttons to move the user through the screens...

the problem is that the site is in hebrew and needs to scroll to the left.

i've been using the scrollTo script to smoothly scroll between screens and testing in firefox and chrome where it works fine.

Internet Explorer however doesn't work at all... when the scrollTo is called to move to object in the negative position it jumps to 0 position.

heres a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/dogstar10/s8cbdy8x/1/

```
$('.panel').click(function() {
    vartarget = "#"+$(this).data("target")
    $('body').scrollTo($(vartarget), 1000);
});

body{direction:rtl;}
.panel{position:absolute; z-index:3; width:250px; height:250px; background:green; top:50px; }
#panel1{left:0; }
#panel2{ left:-400px;}
#panel3{ left:-800px;}
#panel4{ left:-1200px;}

<div class="panel" data-target="panel2" id="panel1"></div>
<div class="panel" data-target="panel3"  id="panel2"></div>
<div class="panel" data-target="panel4"  id="panel3"></div>
<div class="panel" data-target="panel1"  id="panel4"></div>
```

clicking on the squares in FF or chrome and the screen smoothly scrolls to the next square... in IE it appears nothing happens, but if you manually scroll and then click a square it jumps to the first square.

anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery.scrollTo has a setting called `limit` that is `true` by default and enforces boundaries.
Try adding `limit:false`, that might solve it, or not. If the end position was resulting in a negative number, this could keep the plugin from turning it to 0.

[Here](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) are the docs.

UPDATE: Tried it on the jsfiddle, doesn't solve it :(
I'm not sure you can work around it, I modified the demo to use `window.scrollTo()` which is a native method, super low level and still doesn't work.

```
$('.panel').click(function() {
    var target = "#"+$(this).data("target");
    var pos = $(target).offset().left;
    window.scrollTo(pos, 0);
});
```

Regards

Comment: thanks very much for the answer... really not one i wanted though :)... do you think maybe one of the 'normalise' style sheets might fix the issue, or modernizer.js, or is this something undoable at a browser level?

Comment: Honestly I don't have experience with RTL sites, those might fix it but I don't see why. You should be to solve this by not relying on scrolling but rather moving elements with absolute positioning within a still viewport.
Also, you can put a container (div) that doesn't move, put the elements inside it and scroll it rather than the window.
The point is not to scroll to negative positions which is not legal

Comment: yeah, i'd actually just got to that conclusion myself... i'll try and use something like malsup's cycle to try and have the same effect... i hope it works, and i wish i thought of it before :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a mac, so no IE here. However, I've notice that you are pasing the x object itself as a parameter to the `scrollTo` function:

```
vartarget = "#"+$(this).data("target");
$('body').scrollTo($(vartarget), 1000);
```

And it's good to know that chrome, safari, firefox, etc are accepting that, but that parameter should be a number not an object, so I would try this instead:

```
$('body').scrollTo($(vartarget).css('left'), 1000);
```

That way you're sending a number. And you should even strip the `px` just in case.